# Query an object in Parse4J

Tags: java, parse-platform, parse4j

I would like to know if it is possible to get an object, filtering by an attribute of an attribute class.

To be more specific, if I have:

```
Person<br>
-BasicInformation basicInformation

BasicInformation<br>
-Integer identificationNumber
```

I want to retrieve all Person that has `identificationNumber = 9000000`

I should do something like this:

```
ParseQuery<Person> personQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Person.class);    
personQuery.whereEqualTo("basicInformation.identificationNumber", 9000000);
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everybody. I have resolved it.

I had to do the followings steps.

ParseQuery basicInformationQuery =  ParseQuery.getQuery(BasicInformation.class);

basicInformationQuery.whereEqualTo("identificationNumber", 9000000);

And then

ParseQuery personQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Person.class);
personQuery.whereMatchesQuery("basicInformation", basicInformationQuery);

personQuery.find();

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use relational queries. The main query would then query for all Person objects that match the result of your sub-query.

I quickly checked the docs of *Parse4J* and it does not seem to support this so you might need to either implement that yourself or call the [REST-API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-relational-queries) directly.